# Overriding fillInStackTrace for a standard JVM Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, nosuchmethoderror

If I'm using reflection and I want to find if a method is implemented or not, i can use the getMethod() method. This method throws a NoSuchMethodException.

Is there a way to overload the fillInStackTrace of this Exception to optimize the performance ?  Right now, about 40% of the time is spent in this Method.

I'm using a framework using exceptions as a way to perform a certain kind of control flow.

So I don't want to be too invasive. If i'm creating a class extending Throwable and using this new class instead of NoSuchMethodException, I'm having something like:

```
NewException is never thrown in body of corresponding trystatement
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since `getMethod()` calls `new` directly and you can't replace the code for `NoSuchMethodException` since the class is signed and `fillInStackTrace()` is `native`.

Your best bet is to cache calls to `getMethod()` in a central place: Just create a two level map: `Map<Class, Map<String, Method>>` and use a quick lookup without any exception throwing.

Comment: but if i've many many classes, the map is going to be huge. I would have to dramatically change the framework. tough...

Comment: So i've found that calling getMethods and iterating over the array seems to be quicker. Thanks for the help. I was able to wrap the call to getMethod this way.

Answer (score 2):

> My two following points don't exactly solution the title of your question, but I think they could be helpful...

---

I confirm your performance measure.

I read about a solution in a java performance book. We have applied this to our own application, for some exceptions (where the stack trace is not important, and the possible frequency is high). I don't know if you will like it ... ;-)

**Create a unique instance of your Exception class, store it. Throw that instance**.

This seems ideal when you don't want to disturb an existing flow that relies on exceptions.

---

If your compiler complains about the other method not throwing that exception, it is because you chose a checked Exception.
Use a **subclass of RuntimeException** (they are unchecked, so the compiler doesn't know if they are thrown or not, he won't complain).

Comment: Concerning the first solution, I can't do it, since I don't throw the exception. I think my first solution was quite dumb, since I made the mistake of confusing throwing and catching, even if i catch my own exception that doesn't mean that was the one thrown..